# Adding more than one value to dictionary when looping through string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Still super new to Python 3 and have encountered a problem... I am trying to create a function which returns a dictionary with the keys being the length of each word and the values being the words in the string.

For example, if my string is: "The dogs run quickly forward to the park", my dictionary should return 
`{2: ['to'] 3: ['The', 'run', 'the'], 4: ['dogs', 'park], 7: ['quickly', 'forward']}`

Problem is that when I loop through the items, it is only appending one of the words in the string.

```
def word_len_dict(my_string):
    dictionary = {}
    input_list = my_string.split(" ")
    unique_list = []
    for item in input_list:
        if item.lower() not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(item.lower())
    for word in unique_list:
        dictionary[len(word)] = []
        dictionary[len(word)].append(word)
    return (dictionary)

print (word_len_dict("The dogs run quickly forward to the park"))
```

The code returns

```
{2: ['to'], 3: ['run'], 4: ['park'], 7: ['forward']}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Perhaps not giving me the answer freely, but what do I need to look at next in terms of adding the missing words to the list. I thought that appending them to the list would do it, but it's not.

Thank you!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The code as shown will not run.

Comment: What does the first line in your second loop do (`dictionary[len(word)] = []`)?  What effect does it have on the next line?  Look how you handled the previous loop when you encountered a new word.  How could you do the same in this loop (hint: `len(word) in dictionary` will be true if the dictionary has a key equal to the length of the word, and false otherwise)?

Comment: Bugs aside, your problem description and your code seem to disagree.  In your sample expected output, you count "The" and "the" as different words, and you do not change the case, yet your code maps words to lowercase and eliminates duplicate words.  Which is correct?

Comment: My apologies... in the interest of being brief with my question, I tried to avoid asking about the things I already had working within the code (eliminating duplicates), but I understand how not making that clear in the question caused some confusion. Sorry everyone, still very new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve all your problems:

```
def word_len_dict(my_string):
    input_list = my_string.split(" ")

    unique_set = set()
    dictionary = {}

    for item in input_list:
        word = item.lower()
        if word not in unique_set:
            unique_set.add(word)
            key = len(word)
            if key not in dictionary:
                dictionary[key] = []
            dictionary[key].append(word)

    return dictionary
```

You were wiping dict entries each time you encountered a new word.  There were also some efficiencly problems (searching a list for membership while growing it resulted in an O(n**2) algorithm for an O(n) task).  Replacing the list membership test with a set membership test corrected the efficiency problem.

It gives the correct output for your sample sentence:

```
>>> print(word_len_dict("The dogs run quickly forward to the park"))
{2: ['to'], 3: ['the', 'run'], 4: ['dogs', 'park'], 7: ['quickly', 'forward']}
```

I noticed some of the other posted solutions are failing to map words to lowercase and/or failing to remove duplicates, which you clearly wanted.

Comment: you don't need to check the word is in unique_set or not, you define it as set, so values won't duplicate.

Comment: @FatmaT The check is necessary.  It is how it determines if a word is being seen for the first time.  The set is defined in the same loop that uses it.  If you remove the check, the result will change.

Comment: I just realized it is need for key.

Answer (score 2):

you  can create first the list of the unique words like this in order to avoid a first loop, and populate the dictionary on a second step.

```
unique_string = set("The dogs run quickly forward to the park".lower().split(" "))
dict = {}


for word in unique_string:
    key, value = len(word), word
    if key not in dict:         # or dict.keys() for better readability (but is the same)
        dict[key] = [value]
    else:
        dict[key].append(value)

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning an empty list to the dictionary item before you append the latest word, which erases all previous words.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simply resetting the key to an empty list each time, which is why you only get one value (the last value) in the list for each key.

To make sure there are no duplicates, you can set the default value of a key to a *set* which is a collection that enforces uniqueness (in other words, there can be no duplicates in a set).

```
def word_len_dict(my_string):
    dictionary = {}
    input_list = my_string.split(" ")
    for word in input_list:
        if len(word) not in dictionary:
            dictionary[len(word)] = set()
        dictionary[len(word)].add(word.lower())
    return dictionary
```

Once you add that check, you can get rid of the first loop as well. Now it will work as expected.

You can also optimize the code further, by using the `setdefault` method of dictionaries.

```
for word in input_list:
   dictionary.setdefault(len(word), set()).add(word.lower())
```

Comment: I take back my original comment, but it is returning a dict of sets rather than a dict of lists, which it seemed OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way,

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> my_str = "The dogs run quickly forward to the park"
>>> {x:list(y) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_str.split(),key=len), key=lambda x:len(x))}
{2: ['to'], 3: ['The', 'run', 'the'], 4: ['dogs', 'park'], 7: ['quickly', 'forward']}
```

Comment: Two bugs:  (1) you forgot to map words to lowercase (2) you forgot to remove duplicates

Comment: as per OP i can see op dosent bother about lowecase

Comment: @TomKarzes here is OP statement-------- For example, if my string is: "The dogs run quickly forward to the park", my dictionary should return {2: ['to'] 3: ['The', 'run', 'the'], 4: ['dogs', 'park], 7: ['quickly', 'forward']}

Comment: Ok, I see that.  It's not clear what OP really wants, since OP's code maps words to lowercase and attempts to remove duplicates, but the problem description shows mixed case words.  I guess OP doesn't know what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in unique_list:
dictionary[len(word)] = [x for x in input_list if len(x) == len(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This option starts by creating a unique set of lowercase words and then takes advantage of dict's `setdefault` to avoid searching the dictionary keys multiple times.

```
>>> a = "The dogs run quickly forward to the park"
>>> b = set((word.lower() for word in a.split()))
>>> result = {}
>>> {result.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word.lower()) for word in b}
{None}
>>> result
{2: ['to'], 3: ['the', 'run'], 4: ['park', 'dogs'], 7: ['quickly', 'forward']}
```